# Select row by priority of partial values, using T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table (schema below):

```
Items
------
ItemId
UserId
FullURL
```

I want to select one row from it based on two criteria:

1. either has a given partial URL or given domain name in full URL field, but prioritize for partial URL.
2. similarly, prioritize for a given UserId, else return for any user.

I came up with this basic query (trying to do it in a single query), but it doesn't really prioritize the rows as I want:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * 
FROM Items 
WHERE (FullURL LIKE '%website.com/product-132873%' 
       OR FullURL LIKE '%website.com%') 
  AND (UserId = 1 or UserId > 0)
```

The ideal optimized query should return one row that matches (in order of precedence):

- FullURL LIKE '%website.com/product-132873%' (i.e. partial URL) AND UserId=1 (i.e. given user), else
- FullURL LIKE '%website.com/product-132873%' (i.e. partial URL) AND UserId>0 (i.e. any user), else
- FullURL LIKE '%website.com%' (i.e. domain) AND UserId=1 (i.e. given user), else
- FullURL LIKE '%website.com%' (i.e. domain) AND UserId>0 (i.e. any user).

Hope it makes sense.

I'll appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: Provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: can you provide example with data like table data and output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Order by expression which gives the priority you need

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM Items WHERE
(FullURL LIKE '%website.com/product-132873%' OR FullURL LIKE '%website.com%') AND
(UserId = 1 or UserId > 0)
ORDER BY 
 CASE WHEN FullURL LIKE '%website.com/product-132873% THEN 0  ELSE 2 END 
 + CASE WHEN UserId=1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM(SELECT * FROM Items WHERE UserId >= 1)
WHERE
(FullURL LIKE '%website.com/product-132873%' OR FullURL LIKE '%website.com%')
```